What does "block-scaling" mean?
I read a paper about data fusion that used different datasets from various instruments. (SEE THE ATTACHED LINK or the image below)
They mention that after the concatenation of datasets from different sources, "block-scaling" should be implemented.
I understand why they do it; however, I do not understand how they accomplish this.
In Python, we can use sklearn modules for scaling purposes, such as Min-Max Scaler, Standard Scaler (Z-score), and Max Absolute Scaling, among others.

But what does "block-scaling" mean?
When they implement "block-scaling", which method do they use in Python?
Last question: Should this scaling be performed before or after data fusion?


